# How to hide selection panel when i will maximize my graph panel, using extjs 6

Tags: extjs

How to hide selection panel when I will maximize my graph panel. My selection Panel is on West region, Control Panel on north & GraphPanel at center. I am new to extjs please help me by answering this.

```
    .on("click", function() {
       var el = d3.select(this),
           cPanel = pnl.up('mgoPanel').down('mgoControlPanel'), // control Panel
           sPanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel[name=selectpanel]');
       /selection 

       if (el.attr('state') == 'min') {
           if (cPanel) {
               cPanel.setHidden(true);
           }
           if (sPanel) {
               sPanel.setHidden(true);
           }
           el.attr('src', 'resources/images/minimize.png');
           el.attr('state', 'max');
       } else {
           if (cPanel) {
               cPanel.setHidden(false);
           }
           if (sPanel) {
               sPanel.setHidden(false);
           }
           el.attr('src', 'resources/images/maximize.png');
           el.attr('state', 'min');
       }
       mgoPanel.fireEvent('onchartresize', el.attr('state'), mgoPanel);
     });
```

Also `setHidden(true);` for sPanel is not working.

Comment: Please make a fiddle to show your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open your browser console, and find the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: sPanel.setHidden is not a function

The reason being that

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query
```

is not returning a component. If you check the docs or try it in browser console, you will see that it [returns an array](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.ComponentQuery.html#method-query). An array does not have the function `setHidden`, only a component does.

So the solution is to take the first item from the query result:

```
sPanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel[name=selectpanel]')[0];
```